# how do I extract the Arabic text of this PDF file correctly?

Tags: pdf, encoding, arabic

Today i tried to search a Arabic word in a PDF file that contained Arabic content.

All PDF reader soft wares cannot search any Arabic word in this PDF file.

So I dragged PDF file into Firefox browser and selected a area that contained some words by inspect elements and saw this:

`hw ½oiC` instead of `آخرین سخن`

What is type of the encoding used in this PDF file?
how can i encode this to normal text?

Comment: If copy&paste results in "hw ½oiC", the document must likely does not contain the information required for text extraction. The encoding may well be an arbitrary ad-hoc encoding.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to comment on the file you are looking at without seeing it but a good starting point is to try Acrobat and by either copying the text and pasting it into a text editor or doing a search for the text content will reveal if it can be extracted correctly or not.

If it can't be extracted properly then there's a good chance the font is lacking a ToUnicode entry (see Section 9.10.1 of the ISO PDF 32000-1:2008 specification for more information).

Comment: Strictly speaking a **ToUnicode** is only one way to make text extraction possible. Other ways include using a predefined **Encoding** or *ROS* or using marked content with **ActualText** entries.